# How to derive the Newton polynomial with LA

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, interpolation, interpolation-theory

Consider the interpolation problem: find the polynomial through a given set of points $(x_0,y_0),...,(x_n,y_n)$. Suppose we want the polynomial in *newtonian form*:

> $$N(x)=\sum _{j=0}^k[y_0,\ldots ,y_j]\prod _{{i=0}}^{{j-1}}(x-x_{i})$$

Let's define the following matrix $A$.

---

$$
|A|=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
1& x & \dots & x^n & P_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

---

I know how to derive the Lagrange polynomial from $A$, by developing the determinant to the last column.

(**Question**) How do I derive the Newton polynomial from this matrix $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$ we get
$$
\begin{vmatrix}1&x_0&y_0\\ 1&x_1&y_1\\ 1&x&P(x)\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
Subtracing the 1st row from the other rows we arrive at
$$
\begin{vmatrix}1&x_0&y_0\\ 0&x_1-x_0&y_1-y_0\\ 0&x-x_0&P(x)-y_0\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
Now use the Laplace expansion wrt. the 1st column.